# How long will "recently deleted questions" be kept?

Tags: support

How long will an account's "recently deleted questions" be kept? Will that be the same for all SE sites, or vary? I wish they are kept forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SE just soft-delete (the post is there, just that isn't visible) all the posts, so they are kept in the databases forever. Now, in your "recently deleted questions/answers" that appears in your user profile, that will only be kept for 60 days.

Comment: Thanks. Why 60 days? not 0 day or forever?

Comment: @Tim see [what Shog said](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492/213575)