# Is there any way to force erase a deleted question?

Tags: support

I had recently started to formulate a question I wanted to ask on the main site.
In the meantime I thought of a separate unrelated question that required less research.

So I opened up the ask a question page which still had the old question cached and replaced the body of the question with my new one.

This led to a [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377300/why-is-this-directory-size-greater-than-4096-bytes) where the body and title did not match.
I then deleted the question so I could post it fresh with the correct title.
I did this so there wasn't an edit log with a completely unrelated title.

Now when I try to repost the new question it won't let me as it is a repeat of the now deleted question.

[This other question](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3216/how-long-will-recently-deleted-questions-be-kept) from meta implies I will have to wait 60 days for the mistitled question to be purged.

**Is there any way I can speed this process up?**

Comment: Titles can be edited too.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Yep, I'm aware of that. Thank you though. Part of the question says "I did this so there wasn't an edit log with a completely unrelated title.". It seems like editing title would be a more hackish solution, also I still plan to ask the other question.

Comment: No, editing the question title is the correct and obvious thing to do. In my opinion, of course. And yes, I missed the "I did this so there wasn't an edit log with a completely unrelated title".  Reading fail, sorry. Who cares if there is an edit log with a completely unrelated title?

Comment: I'm with Faheem. Thanks for taking the time to try and do it cleanly, but I think you're over thinking it. Just undelete your question, change its title and you're done.

Comment: Okay, fair point. I'll do as suggested. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Do you need to undelete a question to edit it? I recall editing a deleted question recently without undeleting it.

Comment: I had to undelete it before being able to edit.